# Python webapp - moving from testing to production

Tags: python, web-applications, webserver, nginx

I've made a small web app using web.py that I now want to put into production. I dont anticipate this will have very high concurrent use (probably *max* of 5 or so users at any given time, if that).

That said, I dont want to go with the cherry.py server that comes with web.py (and which i have been using for debugging), because one of my main motivations for the app was to learn how to properly put apps in production.

Reading up on options - there seems to be dizzying array of stuff. Tornoado, nginx, lighttpd etc etc. Also stuff like Gunicorn, which I cant quite grasp the use of so far.

It seems WSGI is the way to go - and I wanted some help with what would be an appropriate, relatively easy to administer setup that i can run on an EC2 instance (ubuntu), perhaps using nginx/wsgi. Specifically, do i need gunicorn (or equivalent), and are there any good intros anybody may know of so i can actually get my web.py code running and at least start to understand this jigsaw of various technologies/options?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Available options are:

- apache + mod_python
- apache + mod_wsgi
- lighttpd + mod_fastcgi
- lighttpd + gunicorn
- nginx + gunicorn

I suggest you to go for gunicorn.

Comment: thanks Anand, i've been experimenting with Cherrypy + nginx - but will also try gunicorn now.

Answer (score 0):

[CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org) is a pretty good choice for deployment.  It's a good WSGI server, and is known to work on EC2.  Straightforward mapping of HTTP requests onto your python code.  I have run it behind Apache, behind lighttpd, and by itself.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [Apache](http://apache.org) + [modpython](http://www.modpython.org/). Even though you expect less load, it's always good to be prepared :)

Plus this is a tried and tested setup.